# Point more than 1 domain to my shared server DNS?

Tags: dns, domain-registration, shared-hosting

I have purchased a shared server. I've associated it with my domain `example.com`. I want to start a new blog/website with the domain `example.com`. Can I use the same shared server to host both websites?

I guess I could create a subdomain called `myblog.example.com`. So then I have 2 websites on the same server. But is it possible to then point the domain to that subdomain/server?

For more information:
 - My domain is purchased through GoDaddy. 
 - My shared server is purchased through GoDaddy.
 - My blog domain is a free domain I've got through a 3rd party. Its not associated with the `example.com` at all. I just want to use my shared server space and avoid purchasing a new server.

Comment: You can use DNS to point domains to your server.   The question is whether or not you can associate those domains with your hosting account.   Some hosting packages charge per domain while other allow "add on domains".  To work, your host needs to allow you to put web server configuration in place for each domain and allow you to upload files for it.   What host do you use and what interface do they give you?   cPanel and WHM hosting interfaces are common.

Answer (score 1):

As noted, it depends on your webhost.  So you should start with them.

As an example, we have 3 types of hosting.  the first type (email/basic hosting) does not allow for multiple domains, the second type (CPanel/shared hosting) allows multiple domains, the number can vary based on whether you've upgraded the hosting or not.  the third type (VPS) also allows you to host multiple domains.